# ALS Matrix Convergence

Tags: matrices

I came across this statement in some MapR [documentation on ML in Spark](https://www.mapr.com/blog/parallel-and-iterative-processing-machine-learning-recommendations-spark):

> ALS is an iterative algorithm. During each iteration, the algorithm
>   alternatively fixes one factor matrix and solves for the other. This
>   process continues until it converges. The practice of alternating
>   between which matrix to optimize is why the process is called
>   Alternating Least Squares.

What do they mean by solving for the matrix. Do they mean they multiply each matrix by the other to form the sparse matrix or am I misunderstanding the statement? If so, why would one be in fixed form during the iteration while the other is being "solved", surely multiplication doesn't vary the values in either matrix but only generates new values for the sparse matrix.

Also when do two matrices converge? Is the convergence specific to the fact that we're processing two matrices in parallel?

*Disclaimer: I'm from an engineering background and I struggle with even basic data science. I'm sure I've butchered the theory here so apologies for that. I'm looking for basic understanding so I can further my studies by myself and understand what this statement actually means.*

EDIT: [Documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala#L294) in spark seems to state that we generate the matrices our selves from an existing data set. So this is the "solving" part. So we solve the matrices by actually generating them from the existing data.

Comment: Please do not re-post.  I will migrate this.

Comment: $$\min_{X,Y} \|A - XY\|_F^2 \qquad \qquad s.t. \ \ X_{ij} \ge 0, Y_{ij} \ge 0$$ with $X : N \times K, Y : K \times N$ and $A$ the input $N \times N$ matrix is the non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization it is one of the succesful application of ALS

Comment: note that you can replace ALS with a gradient descent, but in those kind of minimization problems, ALS can be much more efficient (avoiding some of the local minimum where the gradient descent gets stuck)

Comment: there is also the EM algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm which in the case of a Gaussian mixture is also based on ALS

Comment: so all you have to prove is that ALS is guaranteed to converge to a **local** minimum, exactly as the gradient descent, and that if the problem is convex, this local minimum has to be the global minimum